# Regular Expression to validate RGB string value

Tags: regex, vb.net

Looking for a way to validate a comma separated RGB string based value in VB.NET

Numbers cannot be greater than **255** and the following formats are acceptable:

```
"255,255,255"
"025,25,1"
"0,0,0"
```

The values never have spaces between the commas so that's not an issue.

Invalid:

```
"256,255,255"
"255,567,255" 
"255,,255"
"255,255"
etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although attempting range validation in the expression generally increases the complexity of the expression, an example would be:

```
^(?:(?:^|,\s*)([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){3}$
```

This expression looks for the following sequence repeated **exactly three times**:

- Either the start of the string, or a comma followed by whitespace
- Followed by any of the following decimal patterns (captured in a capturing group):

  - a 1-2 digit sequence, optionally preceded by 0 or 1 (covers 000-199, with or without leading zeros), or
  - A 2 followed by 0-4, followed by a digit (covers 200-249), or
  - 25, followed by 0-5 (covers 250-255)
- Followed by the end of the input string

The individual elements (R, G, B) are captured individually (.NET supports multiple captures in the same capturing group) and can be accessed like so:

```
Dim pattern As String = "^(?:(?:^|,\s*)([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){3}$"
Dim input As String = "055,5, 0" ' The input to be matched

Dim r As Regex = New Regex(pattern)
Dim m As Match = r.Match(input)
If Not m.Success Then
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: Not a match", input)
Else
    ' Capture red, green, blue elements from the original string
    Dim red = CInt(m.Groups(1).Captures(0).Value)
    Dim green = CInt(m.Groups(1).Captures(1).Value)
    Dim blue = CInt(m.Groups(1).Captures(2).Value)

    Console.WriteLine("Color: r={0},g={1},b={2}", red, green, blue)
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this patter. It has 3 groups that are the same and match numbers from 0 to 255:

```
^([0-1]?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]),([0-1]?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]),([0-1]?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex isn't very well suited for range validation. I would think a better solution would be to check that it meets the general comma delimited format, then split the string up along the commas and parse the values to integers. You can still use regex to prevent the int parser from failing on invalid formats, e.g.:

```
^\d{1,3},\d{1,3},\d{1,3}$
```

Comment: I agree with your first sentence. I'm in the school of thought that believes the best way to validate this kind of thing is to put `Color.FromArgb()` into a try/catch block and see what comes out. But I have to add that this doesn't mean regex is impossible in this case, and sometimes all you can do is plug a regex into a third-party validation component.